# Xamarin Essentials - Connectivity.NetworkAccess incorrect on Pixel 3?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.essentials

I have a function similar to this:

```
private bool IsConnected()
{
    if (DeviceInfo.DeviceType == DeviceType.Unknown)
        return false;

    var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

    if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

My teammates have reported zero issues with this function, and are using a variety of devices.  My personal device is a Google Pixel 3, using Google Fi and Google VPN.  When I cut it into airplane mode, I see `Connectivity.NetworkAccess` is set to `NetworkAccess.None`. However, when I leave airplane mode off and turn both Mobile Data and Wifi off explicitly, I see `Connectivity.NetworkAccess` is set to `NetworkAccess.Internet`.

Related to this, the `Connectivity.ConnectionProfiles` reports a single profile: `ConnectionProfile.Unknown`.

Is this expected behavior?  Should I check a combination of `Connectivity.ConnectionProfiles` as well as `Connectivity.NetworkAccess` in attempting to determine if the device actually is connected to a network?

Comment: It might be worth debugging at a lower level than the abstraction. Take a look at the [Android APIs being used](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/master/Xamarin.Essentials/Connectivity/Connectivity.android.cs) to further understand and maybe run some of these locally to ensure that it's not hitting an invalid code path.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access the internet and Connectivity.NetworkAccess is NetworkAccess.Internet then it is not expected behavior.

You can submit the issue on their github: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues